# count objects that meet certain condition in List-collection

Tags: c#, .net

I want to count the occurences of objects within a `List<T>` that match a certain condition.
For example like this
`int List<T>.Count(Predicate<T> match)`
So for example if have a list of `chores`, I can see how many are overdue.

```
int overdue = listOfChores.Count((element) => { return element.DueDate <= DateTime.Today; });
```

I know that does not exist and so far I solve problems like that in the following way:

```
int overdue = listOfChores.FindAll([...]).Count;
```

However that allocates and initializes a new List etc. only to get the count.

A way to do this with less allocation overhead etc.:

```
int good = 0;
foreach(chore element in listOfChores)
    if(element.DueDate <= DateTime.Today)
        good++;
```

The last approach can also be exandend to count several conditions without iterating over the loop more than once. (I already found that [*getting* the count property only takes O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517351/does-list-count-physically-iterate-through-the-list-to-count-it-or-does-it-keep), but making the List to count from still eats a lot of time)

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
foreach(chore element in listOfChores)
    if(element.CondA)
        a++;
    if(element.CondB)
        b++;
```

Given this I could even imagine something like
`int[] List<T>.Count(Predicate<T>[] matches)`

My question(s):
Is there such a thing, just I haven't found it yet?
If not: What would be  way to implement such functionality?

**EDIT :**
Adding LINQ looks like it fixes it.

Comment: Which version of c# ? there is [Enumerable.Count<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have a look at the LINQ method Count: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.count(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853010/get-item-count-of-a-list-using-linq

Comment: @NicoD I was on .Net 4.0. I'll give that link a shot right now.

Comment: @AshishRajput good link.

Comment: Without System.Linq you can't use the extension methods like Enumerable.Count<T> that's why you haven't find it yet

Comment: @NicoD I noticed. If you'd type up your helpful advice as a full answer, I could mark it as such ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's is a count method using a predicate : see [Enumerable.Count Method (IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Note that this method is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb383977.aspx) and you can use it only if you add a reference to the System.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 9):

You just have your syntax slightly off.  This is how to use `Count` :

```
int overdue = listOfChores.Count(element => element.DueDate <= DateTime.Today);
```

If you already have a `Predicate<T>` and want to pass it to `Count` just call it like a function:

```
Predicate<Chore> p = (element) => element.DueDate <= DateTime.Today; 

int overdue = listOfChores.Count(element => p(element));
```